# Fixing code style: change double quote strings to single quote in PHP when there are no variables in them

Tags: php, code-standards

I am wondering if there is a tool, that will parse a PHP project and fix a bad code style.

That is a double quoted string that has no variables should be changed to single quote.

```
$var1="change enclosing to single quote"."here too";
$var2="change enclosing in this string but keep $i"."change it here";
```

I would like to rewrite automatically in entire project to:

```
$var1='change enclosing to single quote'.'here too';
$var2='do not change enclosing in this string '.$i.'change it here';
```

Comment: See the answer here: http://www.sematopia.com/2007/08/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/ Having a very big site it turned out it will reduce generation time and reduce server load. That little bit it helps on this project. And it was request by an Audit company.

Comment: @salathe: I think it's a good thing if your code consistent. Several years in programming i tried a lot of practices, now when i need to open my old codes, i'm doing the same - manually.

Comment: Don't you have better things to do? Like actually profiling your application to see where it can be improved?

Comment: The linked PHP official page from that article, says "If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters." I think what's on PHP page is official http://ca.php.net/types.string

Comment: AND SO WHAT? yes, it will interpret. it does mean NOTHING

Comment: The company I work for, doesn't accept this coding style. Either give solution or ignore the question.

Comment: BTW, what about these characters? like "\n" for example? want it being converted too?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel "article been written by a fool" is not an argument

Comment: Seriously, I gotta ask why you ask "Seriously, why"? It's obvious and NOT a lie. But as I know the Col. he's no person for discussions. By the way you can accomplish your goal, with most PHP-IDEs.

Comment: coding style is one thing but these stupid tales about server load is another

Comment: @fabrik coding standards are for people, not people for coding standards. We are programmers, not soldiers. Don't try to standardize every trifle thing. Try to think of algorithm, not of quotes style.

Comment: PHP codesniffer will show these for you so you can change them before you commit code to the repository but this method is preventative not fixing something afterwards...

Comment: @etbal that's a good answer, post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PHP codesniffer will show these for
>   you so you can change them before you
>   commit code to the repository but this
>   method is preventative not fixing
>   something afterwards...

http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected

This is a methodology you should follow when developing.